# Get module of a function (defined stand-alone)

Tags: python-3.x, function, module

I have an object with a dict of functions that I need to store (for example, in JSON). Such functions are not bound to an object nor decorated and are defined *stand-alone* in different modules. Is there a way to programatically get the module where the function is defined?

What I expect:

```
import importlib

class FunctionBag(object):

  @property
  def functions(self)
    return self._functions

  def __init__(self, functions):
    self._functions = functions

  def to_dict_for_json(self):
    result = {}
    for key, fn, in self._functions.items():
      name = fn.__name__
      module = MAGIC(fn)
      result[key] = (module, name,)

  @classmethod
  def FromDictOfJson(cls, dct):
    functions = {}
    for key, value, in dct.items():
      module,name, = value
      module = importlib.import_module(module)
      functions[key] = getattr(module, name)
    return cls(functions)
```

Is there a way to do what MAGIC() does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def foo():
...   pass
... 
>>> foo.__module__
'__main__'
>>> sys.modules[foo.__module__]
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
```